# twitters typeahead.js not showing suggestions

Tags: typeahead.js

I've been trying to add typeahead.js functionality to my search function on my site. But it is not working even though I spent a lot of time playing with it.
Site:digrin.com
Lately I can't even see what I'm typing. If I uncomment this javascript code, I can see text while typing:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[-->
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.typeahead').typeahead({
                name: 'search',
                displayKey: 'name',
                remote: 'search/autocomplete/?q=%QUERY',
                minLength: 1, // send AJAX request only after user type in at least X characters
                limit: 5 // limit to show only 5 results
            });
    });//]]>
    </script>
```

Autocomplete remote json response:
http://www.digrin.com/search/autocomplete/?q=bb
Thanks for any answer in advance!

####################edit1

So thanks to zeropaper  comment I included bloodhound like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[-->
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var search = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: '/search/autocomplete/?q=%QUERY'
        });

        search.initialize();
        $('.typeahead').typeahead(null, {
            name: 'search',
            displayKey: 'name',
            minLength: 1, // send AJAX request only after user type in at least X characters
            limit: 5, // limit to show only 5 results
            source: search.ttAdapter()
        });
});//]]>
</script>
```

Now I can see text while typing, but suggestion box is still not showing up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above is missing the Bloodhound implementation, have a look at the remote example:
http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote

By the way, your CSS styles might also be conflicting (it looks odd to me at first sight).

Comment: Thanks, I can see while typing now. but suggestion box is still not showing up. Should I look for css conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

Change your bloodhound implementation as below.

```
    var search  = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    limit: 1000,
    remote: {
        cacheKey: 'search',
        url: "http://www.digrin.com/search/autocomplete/",
        replace: function(url, query) {
               return url + "?q=" + query;
        },
        filter: function(search) {
            return $.map(search, function(data) {
                    return {
                        tokens: data.tokens,
                        symbol: data.symbol,
                        name: data.name
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have tried your code and its not working. What am I missing? Your version is up on digrin.com

Comment: @Lucas03 I tried this code, its working fine for me. Are you sure running this code from www.digrin.com domain ? because Cross-Origin policy blocks fetching data from other domains. check for any console also ??

Comment: Also try putting these lines in ur code. search.clearPrefetchCache(); search.initialize(); search.clearPrefetchCache();

Comment: Hi, that is weird. I uploaded your code to digrin.com, so that you can check.

Comment: I dnt have registred account on digrin. Can i see ur complete code there ?..Well m making an account there to see it.

Comment: its the same for visitors as for registered members. Or user:"test" and pass:test.